# Multiple Inheritance in Visual C++ .NET

Tags: c++, .net, multiple-inheritance

Multiple Inheritance of classes is allowed in C++, however .NET does not allow this, so how does Multiple Inheritance of classes work in Visual C++ .NET?

**EDIT:**

Ok, based on the comments it seems that this question is somewhat unclear. I understand that .NET is a framework, not a language, and I also understand that .NET is CLR/CLS compliant.

My point is that if C++ allows MI, when I come to writing an application using Visual C++ .NET, can I still use MI or does .NET prevent this in order to maintain CLR/CLS compliancy?

If I can use MI in VC++.NET...

1. why is it possible in VC++.NET but not C#.NET/VB.NET?
2. does this have any limitations compared with traditional C++?
3. How does this impact the usage of .NET in VC++?

Comment: ".NET" isn't a programming language.

Comment: The premise is wrong. .NET does allow multiple inheritance.

Comment: Noop, the CLR allows only single inheritance.

Comment: .NET is just a framework, i.e. a set of classes and functions. C# is a language that uses .NET, and the _language_ disallows multiple inheritance. C++ is another language, and it allows multiple inheritance. However, if it's a good idea to use multiple inheritance with .NET base classes is another question.

Comment: @devundef http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/07/why-doesn-t-c-support-multiple-inheritance.aspx

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, it says that is possible to create code using MI however this code will not be CLS compliant,  ie its not part of the CLR. In other words you can create MI code but it will not be reausable by other compilers like VB, ironpython, f#, etc...

Comment: @KerrekSB, although .net is not a language, Matthew make his point in the question. The .net clr do not supports MI, its not a language issue. Any language that compiles targeting the .net clr must follow the same rules (cls).

Comment: Matthew, take a look at this:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761733/why-does-vb-net-not-support-multiple-inheritance

Comment: @devundef, Thanks for your last post. That seems quite informative.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem

Comment: What is C++ .Net? Perhaps you meant C++/CLI. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163852.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++/CLI is a full C++ with some extra features for defining and manipulating CLI objects easily. It's purpose is to allow taking a C++ library and making it available to C# or other CLI language (kind of like JNI, but integrated in compiler to make it a lot easier to use). To achieve this, it has two ways to define a class:

- If you define a class with just `class`, it will create a C++ class exactly as it would without the `/CLI` option. It can have multiple inheritance, but is not visible by bytecode-compiled code (C#, VB.NET, JavaScript etc.).
- If you want to define a CLI class and use it from C#, than you declare it with `ref class` and that does *not* allow multiple inheritance.

It does this exactly because the object models are not compatible, so the C++ classes can't be used directly.